# Scala & ScalaTest operator === conflict

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalaz

I want to test operator `===` of `Scalaz` using `ScalaTest`.
I have written simply test:

```
class ComparisonTest extends FunSuite {

  test("=== operator of Scalaz") {
    assert(1 === 1) // i want to check/test === operator of Scalaz
  }
}
```

Unfortunately within `assert` of my test, scala picked operator `===` from `ScalaTest`. It did not help if I import explicitly:

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._
import scalaz._
```

I also tried:

```
import scalaz.syntax.EqualOps
assert(new EqualOps[Int](1).===(1))  }
```

but it did not compile:

```
Error:(10, 12) constructor EqualOps in class EqualOps cannot be accessed in class ComparisonTest
    assert(new EqualOps[Int](1).===(1))  }
```

Is there any way to do such test of `Scalaz` `===`operator within test of `FunSuite`? (maybe somhow disable `===` of `ScalaTest`)

Comment: Welcome to my life. :) We ended up defining our own `====` operator which requires an implicit instance of scalaz Equal[A].

Comment: Yes, that is an option and work around that I also found, but I just wonder if it is possible to do such test without an extra operator.

Comment: If you find something interesting, please post here :) I was even considering moving to other testing libraries just because of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `new EqualOps[Int](1).===(1))` error, you can use `implicitly[Equal[Int]].equal(1, 2)` to `implicitly` get **Scalaz** `Equal` implementation.

For **disable scalatest Equalizer implicit conversion**, you can try to override `convertToEqualizer` method and **remove `implicit` method modifier**.

Example:

```
class ComparisonTest extends FunSuite {
  override def convertToEqualizer[T](left: T): Equalizer[T] = new Equalizer(left)

  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._

  test("=== operator of Scalaz") {
    assert(1 === 1) // i want to check/test === operator of Scalaz
  }
}
```

this is a tricky way to achieve this, best way maybe need **scalatest** change **Equalizer** inject way, like by import, and we can **unimport** the `implicit` like: `import Predef.{any2stringadd}`